# How to project position in ProseMirror state to converted into Markdown string

Tags: markdown, caret, prose-mirror

Imagine we have WISYWIG/Markdown editor with switching between modes like in [official example here](https://prosemirror.net/examples/markdown/).

Notice that it doesn't keep your caret/scroll/selection when you toggle modes. If we are going further in improving it's UX, we ned to keep caret position when switching modes.

The issue is that cursor position in WISYWIG, say: "foo **b|ar**" is "5", while in raw markdown position would be "foo **b|ar**" – "7".

How could these positions be projected back and forward when switching modes?

If we solve position projection problem, the "scroll" and "selection" synchronisation are just a little tweaks to do.

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution to the problem:
We just need to mark target position with some very sepcial symbol, pass the convertor and find where this marker is now. It is relatively simple, robust and straight-forward solution.

```ts
import {schema, defaultMarkdownParser,
        defaultMarkdownSerializer} from "prosemirror-markdown"
import {Node, Slice, Fragment} from 'prosemirror-model';

// We need a special symbol which is likely not used in text
const MARKER = '█';

function projectToProsemirror(mdText: string, position: number): number {
  const withMarker = mdText.substr(0, position) + MARKER + mdText.substr(position);

  const node = defaultMarkdownParser.parse(withMarker);

  return node.textContent.indexOf(MARKER);
}

function projectToMarkdown(node: Node, position: number): number {
  const pos = node.resolve(position + 1 /* prosemirror counts position from "1" */);

  const marker = Fragment.from(schema.text(MARKER, pos.marks()));

  const withMarker = node.replace(pos.pos, pos.pos, new Slice(marker, 0, 0));

  const markdown = defaultMarkdownSerializer.serialize(withMarker);
  return markdown.indexOf(MARKER);
}
```

## Usage:

`projectToProsemirror('some **formatted** text', 8); // = 6`